# Optimize SQL query by eliminating extensive GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, query-optimization

I have a query with multiple select and a single aggregated value, coming from a joined table, resulting an extensive and ugly GROUP BY (because of the one-to-many relation with the joined table).
It's something like this:

```
SELECT user.id, user.name, user.type, etc.
GROUP_CONCAT(car.id SEPARATOR ', ') AS cars
FROM user
INNER JOIN car ON user.id = car.userid
GROUP BY user.id, etc.
ORDER BY user.name, user.type, cars
```

I would like to eliminate the long GROUP BY, but how could I get the aggregated value without the JOIN? Is there a way with something like a subquery to join the values together like with the GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: You could use a *lateral join*; your query as written looks broken though, *INNER JOIN user.id ON car.userid* is a syntax error?

Comment: Is user.id a table name?

Comment: GROUP BY cars first, JOIN the result with users.

Comment: Lateral joins are available since MySQL 8.0.14. What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate in `car` and then join to `user`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.type, etc.,
       c.cars
FROM user u
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT userid, GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ') AS cars 
  FROM car 
  GROUP BY userid
) c ON u.id = c.userid
ORDER BY u.name, u.type, c.cars;
```

Or with a correlated subquery, which is equivalent to  a `LEFT` join but may perform better:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.type, etc.,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.id SEPARATOR ', ') FROM car c WHERE u.id = c.userid) AS cars 
FROM user u
ORDER BY u.name, u.type, cars;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group this way

```
SELECT user.id, user.name, user.type,
       uc.cars
FROM (
   SELECT userid, GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ') AS cars
   FROM car
   GROUP BY userid) uc
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = uc.userid
```